# Preroll Html5 autoplay Video

Tags: html, html5-video

I have problem with html5 player.

```
<video id="videoPlayer" src="ads-video.mp4"   width="604" height="340" autobuffer controls />

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var nextVideo = "video-video.mp4" ;
    var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
    videoPlayer.addEventListener('ended', function(){
            videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;

            }, false);

    </script>
```

when video add is ended i want that video-video start automatically , who can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

That code should work if you just put the autoplay attribute in the video tag. If you don't want it to autoplay the ads, you can set videoPlayer.autoplay = true in the event listener.